# Canvas how to remove background image

Tags: html, canvas, background

I use HTML5 canvas and javascript writing like a paint program.

**I have background image:**
[image: I have background image]

**After drawing get (background+drawings) this result:**
[image: After drawing get (background+drawings) this result:]

**Now i need clear background i get this result:**
[image: Now i need clear background i get this result]

I add two tries button "Change background" and "Delete background" because if i can change background i can put white background and get result like clean background.

```
me code: http://jsfiddle.net/3zj3z/
```

**This change background code works but not showing drawings after it:**

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://static3.businessinsider.com/image/52a0bbfd6bb3f7961363819e/the-most-amazing-satellite-images-of-the-year.jpg";
ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);
```

**Second button doesn't work i don't know how to make it me try:**

```
$("#btn2").click(function() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 0; //img.src = "" not working
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);               
});
```

Comment: You can use ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height) to clear all drawings and leave a blank canvas. Then you can redraw anything that you want onto the blank canvas.

Comment: You can have 2 canvas on top of each other. One to manage your background and another to manage the drawing. This way, you wont have to redraw anything if you change/clear your background or if you erase parts of drawing.

Comment: i try situation with two canvas but i cannot make both actives, because where drawing need active if drawing, background need active too because need to zoom it... maybe u know how to make both actives